# Energy Transport in Circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, physics, circuit-theory

I've been reading about how energy is actually transported in circuits (I first read about it here: http://amasci.com/miscon/ener1.html). The description in this article of why electrons don't move around the circuit carrying energy like buckets, picking up energy from the battery and dumping it at the load, is reasonable to me, some points in particular being that electron drift velocity in circuits is actually very low and that in AC circuits electrons don't even drift along the entire length of the circuit but rather oscillate, so they don't even travel from sources to loads and back. Instead, it's electromagnetic waves that carry energy through a circuit.

I can accept this but now I'm confused about how you would interpret calculations of energy transfer in terms of electrons, calculations which also seem reasonable to me but seem to contradict the arguments above.

For example, suppose you have a 9 volt battery and you want to increase its *energy* by 500 J. Since a volt is J/C, \$ \Delta E = V \Delta C \rightarrow \Delta C = \frac{\Delta E}{V} \rightarrow \Delta C = \frac{500 J}{9 J/C} \approx 55.56\ Coul\$. Converting this into electrons, this is about \$ 3.47*10^{20}\$ electrons.  This seems to suggest that you would physically need this number of electrons to pass between the terminals of the battery to transfer this energy. Is this calculation invalid? If not, how do you interpret this calculation in terms of electromagnetic waves?

Answer (score 2):

> This seems to suggest that you would physically need this number of electrons to pass between the terminals of the battery to transfer this energy. Is this calculation invalid? If not, how do you interpret this calculation in terms of electromagnetic waves?

With respect to your battery, when it provides one Coulomb of charge, oxidation in the anode really does cause 6E18 electrons to leave negative terminal, and a further 6E18 electrons to enter the positive terminal where they reduce a similar number of ions.

The point being made in your source is that it isn't the same electrons leaving one side as arriving at the other.  Electrons are all interchangeable, and the ones going into the positive terminal probably started very, very close to where they ended up.  You can think of electric field as pushing one electron a slight distance, which repulses another electron, which repulses another... until finally far down the chain one electron will reach the positive terminal and reduce an ion.

In addition, you can apply the same reasoning to the movement of ions in the battery cell itself, which also move under the effect of the cell voltage:

[image: Battery cell diagram]

Taken from [wikipedia's article on galvanic cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell).

Comment: Long ago we could buy little "operating hours" gauges like a glass mercury thermometer.  It was a mercury column with a little gap full of HgCl solution or similar.  When DC was applied, one end would electroplate and the other dissolve, so over many months the little gap would move along! Interesting part: if each mercury atom provides one mobile electron inside the metal, then the little gap is moving at half the speed of the electron-flow.  To grow 1mm of extra metal onto the tip of the column, we need 1mm of extra electrons, plus 1mm of extra trip, for them to reach the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 55 Coulombs is about 350 x 10<sup>18</sup> electrons, and that's what you need for 500 J at 9 V.

What's the problem?

It's a big number. What size number were you expecting?

Put a cut plane across anywhere in the circuit, and that's the total number of charge carriers that would cross it. In the wire, electrons are the charge carriers. In the battery, it's ions.

I'm afraid that to work with both electrons and EM waves properly, you probably need to get into QED, Quantum Electro Dynamics. But crudely, electrons will tend to drift in the direction of the electric field (or against it, sign convention).

Answer (score 1):

Just because electrons are not moving around the entire circuit carrying buckets of charge, does not mean they are not moving. A single electron (on average, over a long time) only moves very slowly.

A good analogy for this is to think of a pipe filled with water. If I create a lot of pressure on one end of the pipe, this pressure is 'transported' to the other end of the pipe. However, the individual water molecules will not have to move the entire length of the pipe to do so, instead they transfer this pressure among each other down the pipe. 
The same happens with electrons - the individual electron does not have to move across the entire circuit to transfer the power.

Sticking with the water-pipe analogy: If there is a slight flow due to my pressure, billions of trillions of water molecules might be coming out the other end every second. At any cross section along the pipe, you will find this same amount of water atoms passing by every second. Since they are so small, and there are so many of them, even with very slow movement of water, huge numbers are actually moving.

This is the same with electrons in a conductor carrying current.

Answer (score 0):

In many ways the incorrect "coal cars" or "energy buckets" explanation is less problematical.  If you're not planning on a science/engineering career, then the "lies to children" will make things far less complicated and daunting.  But if you really really want to know how circuits actually work, then basic EM is the way to go.

Notice that, during the EM energy-flow, the circuit's voltage is the "E" part, and the loop of current is the "M" part.  A physicist must take the "vector cross-product" E X M: multiply the e-field with the b-field to calculate the electromagnetic energy-density at any point surrounding the wires.

But we have it easy: just multiply volts times amps to get the total energy-flow, in joules per second.

In a 2-wire cord, roughly half the e-field is near each wire, and since in the two wires, both the e-field and the current are opposite, multiplying them together gives us some watts which are flowing in the same direction along both wires, each wire guiding half the total energy from the supply to the load.

In circuits, electric current relates to magnetism because any simple circuit is actually a 1-turn inductor.  Find textbook chapters discussing "Amp-turns" as a magnetism unit.

All of this is relating DC circuits with radio waves running through coaxial cable and spewing out from antennas.  That works all the way down to DC, but then of course for "DC transmitters" we'd need a dipole antenna that's many light-hours wide!  (Or, plug a 75-ohm dipole into 120VAC, and if the dipole is half-wave resonant at 60Hz, how many watts of 60Hz radio is transmitted?   Heh.

ALSO:

What's the physical size of one coulomb?  In copper wire?  It's about the size of half a grain of salt. See my article:  http://amasci.com/miscon/speed.html#width
If we send about 2amps through #30 gauge wire, the coulombs are moving at about 1mm per second.  Gets hot though.